# PHPMyAdmin Cannot use PHP to Insert data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I'm using MAMP Server to host a MySQL database to store some information about user accounts.

When I try to insert an entry using the code given by PHPMyAdmin, it won't insert it. Could somebody please tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
<?php
$username = "username";
$password = "*******"; 
$hostname = "localhost:8889"; 

$inputUsername = $_POST["username"];
$inputPassword = $_POST["password"];
$confirmPassword = $_POST["confirmPassword"];

if ($inputPassword != $confirmPassword) {
    die("Your two password entries are not the same!");
}

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$sql = mysql_select_db("billet",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select database");

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `billet` (`username`, `password' VALUES ('$inputUsername', '$inputPassword')");    


echo "Inserted values! <a href='index.html'>Go</a>";

mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: I'm missing `the code given by PHPMyAdmin`

Comment: try `print mysql_error();` after mysql_query(); (better yet....`if (!mysql_query(...)) { print mysql_error(); } else { print "updated"; }` )

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the database to insert the data that you want, currently you are just connecting to the database and then closing.

You will need to do something like this (depending on your MySQL table) :

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `billet` (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('$inputUsername', '$inputPassword')");
```

You should also think about switching to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: I tried using your code and it doesn't seem to work. (I've edited the code I posted to show the INSERT. I actually did have a line that inserted the values, but I forgot to put it in.

Comment: Can you add a picture of what your MySQL table looks like, it will be a big help. Also you should turn on error reporting and add anything that it outputs using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`